# Prove that interval $(0,1]$ is not compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to prove that interval $(0,1]$ is not compact by showing it doesn't have **Heine-borel** property.

I know a set is compact if a set is closed and bounded or has BW property or has Heine-borel property. But I'm trying to use heine-borel property to prove that it is not compact. I know I have to use the definition of open cover to prove this, but I don't know how to begin.

my guess: in order to prove $(0,1]$ is not compact by showing it doesn't have heine-borel property, is to show that there exists open cover $(0,1]$ that cannot be reduced to a finite subcover. but then what would be $\mathscr{U}$?

Comment: take the obvious open cover: the collection $(1/n,2)$, say, for positive integers $n$.

Comment: sorry i don't understand open cover too well. how is $(1/n,2)$ an obvious open cover? @symplectomorphic

Comment: sorry, what is the Heine Borel property?

Comment: state the definition of an open cover and think about my example.

Comment: @symplectomorphic ah i was dumb. i can even make $(1/2^n,2)$

Comment: @symplectomorphic i thought both endpoint of intervals must be covered. like (-1,2) is an open cover.

Comment: @Jorge: what does that even mean? I'm not a bro, and I'm perfectly chill. my response was to the OP, and it had precisely the right effect: she now undertstands.

Comment: @Allie: $(-1,2)$ *is* an open cover of $(0,1]$. but compactness requires that *every* open cover have a finite subcover.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Sorry about miss-characterizing you as a bro. Its just that your comment came off as bossy to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to construct an open cover for which no finite subcover can still cover all of the interval $(0,1]$. One way you might do this is to take a collection of covers $U_n = (a_n, 2)$, where $a_n \to 0$.

If you create $a_n$ such that all $a_n > 0$, then clearly no finite subcover will still cover the interval.

Answer (score 2):

Define $I_{n} = (\frac{1}{n}, 2)$

Then 
$$
\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_{n}
$$
covers $(0,1]$ but it's easy to see that finitely many $I_{n}$ can't cover the interval. This is because if a finite cover $\{I_{n}\}_{n=1}^{k}$ existed, then this would not cover $(0, \frac{1}{k})$ and thus wouldn't be a cover at all.

Comment: Can the downvoter(s) explain?